# Algorithm for unbiased random derangement

Tags: probability, permutations, algorithms, derangements

I am looking for an algorithm that generates a derangement with uniform probability across all possible derangements.

This is similar to [Generating a random derangement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/generating-a-random-derangement), but with the requirement that the randomness is unbiased, i.e. every derrangment has equal opportunity of being selected.

I have tried the algorithm described [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972986.7) and [here](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/analco08.pdf), but they offer no such claim, and do not seem to be able to generate every derangement. For example, it does not generate (2,1,4,5,3).

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `rand` function for that matter?

Comment: @barakmanos, yes, if not, it would be impossible.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm described in the first of your two quoted links can produce $(2,1,4,5,3)$ without any problem:
$\require{enclose}$
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & \underline5 & 4 & \underline3\\
1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3\\
1 & 2 & \underline4 & \underline5 & 3\\
1 & 2 & \enclose{circle}{4} & 5 & 3\\
\underline{2} & \underline1 & \enclose{circle}{4} & 5 & 3\\
\end{matrix}$$

1. initial state,
2. $3\leftrightarrow5$,
3. $p\ge\frac{4D_3}{D_5}$, marks nothing,
4. $4\leftrightarrow5$,
5. $p\lt\frac{3D_2}{D_4}$, marks $\enclose{circle}{4}$,
6. $1\leftrightarrow2$

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that derangements are like perfect matchings in a very dense bipartite graph. If you are not familiar with the concept of bipartite graphs or matchings, this might be unnecessarily confusing.

Given a set $[n] = \lbrace 1, \dots, n \rbrace$, consider a bipartite graph $G$ with $n$ vertices $l_{1},\dots, l_{n}$ on the left 
and $n$ vertices $u_{1},\dots, u_{n}$ on the right,
with $l_{i}$ being connected with all vertices on the right except the $u_{i}$.
You could think that vertex $l_{i}$ corresponds to the $i$th position of the desired derangement, while $u_{j}$ corresponds to value $j$: position $i$ can be assigned any value in $[n]$ except value $i$. 
A perfect matching in $G$ corresponds exactly to a derangement of $[n]$.

I found this article that points to $2$ papers that apparently describe a method to sample almost uniformly a perfect matching:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10756/sampling-perfect-matching-uniformly-at-random
Maybe you could check those. If not, maybe looking for algorithms to randomly sample perfect matchings from (dense) bipartite graphs could help expanding your search.