# Random pairing of elements between two sets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms, random

I need an efficient ($O(n)$) algorithm that pairs two sets of objects.

So given $A=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2, ... b_m\}$, I need to find $N=\textrm{min}(n, m)$ number of random (uniformly distributed) pairs $P=\{\{a_{i_1}, b_{i_1}\}, \{a_{i_2}, b_{i_2}\}, ... \{a_{i_N}, b_{i_N}\}\}$.

The complication is, that in general it could happen that $a_i=b_j$ (for some $i$ and $j$), so sets can include same objects, but pairing has to be done only with distinct objects, i.e., in the pair $\{a_{i_j}, b_{i_j}\}$, $a_{i_j} \ne b_{i_j}$.

I had a simple approach in mind, where you randomly permute $A$ and $B$ (via e.g. Knuth algorithm), then pick the first $N$ from each set, and trivially pair corresponding elements. The problem is that way I might pair same two elements (since $A$ and $B$ contain some common elements).

I could in principle check for that and pair again with another random element, but I'm not sure if the result is going to be uniformly distributed across all the possible pairing sets.

PS. I recognize, that in some situations the number of possible pairings can be very small ($A=\{a, b\}$, $B=\{b, a\}$ - one possible way to pair). Would be nice if the algorithm can account for that as well.

PPS. Maybe I'm just hunting a unicorn and there is no good way, just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: The problem with "pair again with another random element" is that you can get stuck. E.g. if $A=B=\{1,2,3\}$ and your first two steps pair $(1,2), (2,1)$ then you're stuck. In fact, in the special case of $A=B$, you are looking for a uniform random derangement. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/generating-a-random-derangement) has a good discussion and good starting points for further search.  (I know in your case it is not necessarily true that $A=B$, but your algo must also solve that special case. So techniques for solving that might be useful to your general problem.)

Comment: OTOH if the overlap is very minimal in practice, then I'd think a rejection-based approach would work fine, i.e. permute the larger set and line it up against the smaller one, and if this includes a pair of equal objects, then restart from the very beginning.  Even for perfect overlap $A=B$ such an approach only needs $e \approx 3$ tries on average.  For minimal overlap the expected number of tries will be even less.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that as well. In practice, actually, I wanted a single ubiquitous algorithm to deal both with $A=B$ (random pairing within a single set), $A\ne B$ (no common elements), and sometimes $A\approx B$ (some common elements).

Comment: I don't know your practical situation, but are you sure rejection-based approach is not good enough?  That's _really_ easy and even in the worst case converges in $3$ tries on average.  :)

Comment: You're right, but the problem is (as you said) you may easily end up in a situation like this: $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{4,5,2\}$, and $P=\{\{1, 5\}, \{3, 4\}, \{2, 2\}\}$. What do you do then? In principle, you could swap two elements in two pairs in that case, e.g., $P=\{\{1, 5\}, \{3, 2\}, \{2, 4\}\}$. But then I'm no longer sure this is uniformly distributed. Ofc, I can invent lots of hacks to deal with this, I was just wondering if there is a "proper" way.

Comment: What I mean is, if any pairing doesnt work (because the two objects are equal), then restart from the very beginning.  Retrying just that pair might get you stuck, so retry the whole thing.  In the worst case of $A=B$, for large $n$ any permutation has a $1/e$ chance of being a derangement, so on average you need $e \approx 3$ tries (every re-try starting from the very beginning).  If the overlap is smaller, you will need $< e$ tries on average.

Comment: Got it. Yes, that might be a good way, actually. Is there a situation when I can get stuck redoing infinitely many times though (other than a trivial case when, say, $A=B=\{1\}$)? In other words, is there a nice way to understand how many pairs (if any) I should be expecting from two sets of sizes $m$ and $n$ (max number is obviously $\textrm{min}(m,n)$).

Comment: You do have to check for $A=B$ and size $1$.  Other than that, "redoing infinitely many times" is basically similar to flipping Heads every time in coin flips.  In practice it won't happen unless you have a very, very bad randomizer - in which case, you should consider it a software bug and put in a better randomizer.  The expected number of bad pairs (where two objects are equal) is ${|A \cap B| \over \max(m, n)}$ but is not that relevant.  The relevant number is $Prob(\text{some pair is bad})$ which is harder to calculated but upper bounded by $1 - 1/e$ (for large $m,n$).